# Trying to make 2 boxplots on the same graph using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to complete an assignment using some fake data. One thing they would like us to do is make graphs.

The data is time for students `n=150` to complete a task pre and post an intervention.

I have been able to make graphs like this

```r
Boxplot1 <- ggplot(data, aes(Timepre))
Boxplot1 <- Boxplot1 + geom_boxplot()
Boxplot1
Boxplot2 <- ggplot(data, aes(Timepost))
Boxplot2 <- Boxplot2 + geom_boxplot()
Boxplot2
```

But I would like both to be on the same graph

How can I combine these please?

Comment: See for example the `gridExtra` package. Also, there are a lot of related questions on this site.

Comment: It is ggplot2 that we have been instructed to use.

Answer (score 2):

From your example I gather you have your data as two vectors with values. The most difficult part about this question is probably getting the data in the right shape.

Below, I'll make two vectors of length 150 with some random values.

```r
library(ggplot2)

Timepre <- rpois(150, 30)
Timepost <- rpois(150, 20)
```

ggplot likes to work nicely with data that is in the so called 'long' format, meaning that every observation gets a row of its own in a `data.frame`. We'd need an extra variable, which we'll call `x`, to keep track of the groups.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c("Pre", "Post"), c(length(Timepre), length(Timepost))),
  y = c(Timepre, Timepost)
)

# You might want to encode the groups as factors with levels in sensible orders
df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = c("Pre", "Post"))
```

After reshaping the data, plotting is not so difficult and you can probably find hundreds of posts on this site that can show you how to do it.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>